# How can i enable panning for the whole axis ranges in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In highcharts i can configure axis `min` and `max`. Using these values i can define the range displayed no matter what the actual chart data says.

When zooming in, the `min`/`max` settings are still respected. But when i pan i can only move the chart until the extreme data points appear on the edge of the chart (and not move back if this has not happened yet).

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0bL2r3f9/

Is it somehow possible to enable panning up to the axis' set `min`/`max` values?

Comment: Notice that even if `min and max` values are not defined it is not possible to panning outside the initial chart range. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nur5y8wv/ Would you like to set some custom range values after zoom trigger? How those values should be calculated?

Comment: If it was possible to set a custom panning range that would be fine. Actually i just want to be able to pan along the whole set axis range. I can achieve this behaviour by adding another scatter series, that is not visible: https://jsfiddle.net/0h92jbfk/1/. This seems like a hack to me and i'd prefer a cleaner solution if possible.

Comment: I am afraid that the solution that you shared is the easiest one without interference into the core code.